# nginx Reverse Proxy to a Subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using an nginx reverse proxy to hit multiple different servers.  However, I've found a case I cannot seem to make work.  How do you make the proxy forward to a subdirectory?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain_1.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/subdir_1;
        }
 }

 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain_2.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/subdir_2;
        }
 }
```

Ideally, I would like the user to see subdomain1/2 without the subdir URL passed back in the browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: One observation... Your `proxy_pass` statements are missing a trailing `/`. This will ensure that the URI `/foo` is mapped to `/subdir/foo` rather than `/subdirfoo`.

Answer (score 0):

Your are searching for the `proxy_redirect` feature. See the [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

You need something like this - depending on backend configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain_1.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/subdir_1/;
        proxy_redirect http://hostname:port/subdir_1/ /;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain_2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/subdir_2/;
        proxy_redirect /subdir_2/ /;
    }
}
```